# Data not loading into dynamically loaded html table using datatables

Tags: datatables

I am new to datatables from datatables.net and I am hoping you guys can help me with my issue. My code dynamically loads an html table into the index page (this is a one page web app). My issue is I am having no luck in loading the data into the table.

I can see the data in the function tbody_data(dataSet) by using document.write(JSON.stringify(dataSet));. The data looks correctly formed but no data gets loaded into the table.

Below is the code for the index page (only listed  section for simplicity), the html table that gets loaded into the index page, the js/jquery code that retrieves the data from the database, and the actual data returned by the js/jquery code.

```
<body>
    <div id="container1" class="inline-block">
        <input id="search-input" class="input-control" type="text" size="25" value="">          
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="butonclick="getPlants()">Search</button>       
    </div>

    <div id="container2"></div>     

    <script src="js/pl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common.js"></script>
    
</body>
```

```
function getPlants(){
    var dataSet = '';
    var Search_Value = $("#search-input").val();
        Search_Value = Search_Value.trim();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',                               
            url: "php/get_plants.php",
            data: "searchText="+Search_Value,
            datatype: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    dataSet = JSON.parse(data);
                function tbody_data(dataSet){
                    //document.write(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
                    //return;
                    $("#grid_plants").dataTable({
                                    data: dataSet,
                                    fixedHeader: true,
                                    deferRender: true,
                                    paging: false,
                                    columns: [
                                            { 'data': 'id' },
                                        { 'data': 'plantname' }
                                        ]
                            });
                $("#container2").load("html/grid_plants.html",tbody_data);
            }
                error: function(status) {
                        alert(status);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

File /html/grid_plants.html below:

```
<table id="grid_plants">
    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Plants</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody_plants"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>         
                    <th>Plants</th>
                </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Data returned by ajax call in get_plants():

```
[["1","Sweet Birch"],["2","River Birch"],["3","Yellow Birch"],["4","Chinese Red Birch"]]
```

Comment: Use the DataTables built-in Ajax functionality instead of JQuery Ajax. [Choose an option for your data source from this list](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/).

Comment: The DataTable ajax choices do not seem to include a way to past a piece of text to be used as a parameter in the where clause of the sql statement, am I missing something? Please point me to an example that does include passing a parameter for the sql statement where clause.

Comment: Check out the comment on the `ajax.reload()` documentation page https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() . [Here's another example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33257/reload-ajax-with-modified-post-parameters)

Comment: Thanks mark_b for answering my question.  Would this code still be valid to use with Datatables?  https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html